# What is the TypeError: require(...)(...) is not a function when I try to run my playWright script?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I am currently moving parts of my automation scripts to different files to maintain the whole script more easily, and I encounter this issue.

```
$ node ./playWright/index
    D:\Lambda\projects\puppeteer_test\playWright\index.js:6
    })();
  ^

TypeError: require(...)(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Lambda\projects\puppeteer_test\playWright\index.js:6:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your index.js startup function from

```
(async () => { // Start of async arrow function
  // Function code
  // ...
})(); // End of the function and () to invoke itself
```

To a normal async function

```
async function index() {
  await downloadFile()
  console.log("Test")
}
```